# PyCollada : recalculate the normals

Tags: python, collada, normals

I'm using PyCollada to change vertices's positions.
Then I want to recalculate the normals to correct it.
I'm using the function 'generate_normals.generateNormals(mesh)' but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Does your triangleset already have normals in it? It looks like the [generate_normals](https://github.com/pycollada/meshtool/blob/master/meshtool/filters/optimize_filters/generate_normals.py) method only generates normals if they don't already exist.

Comment: Hi, you are right, I changed the function to recalculate the normal even if it already exists but I still get wrong normals.
Do you have any idea how can I correct them? 
And thank you.